# How can I obtain NP and VP subtrees in Stanford parser using a Spanish model

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

Actually I work in triplets extraction from Spanish text using Java. I need extract those triplets of the form `NP-VP-NP`. I'm using Stanford Parser CoreNLP v 3.7.0 and Spanish model v 3.7.0 too. My questions is next, Is there a way to extract NP subtrees and VP subtrees from a sentence in the spanish model? I realize that Spanish parser tree form is diferent from english form.

Ex:

`(ROOT (sentence (sn (spec (da0000 El)) (grup.nom (nc0s000 reino))) (grup.verb (vmm0000 canta) (sadv (spec (rg muy)) (grup.adv (rg bien))) (fp .)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the main distribution to make sure you have everything and download the Spanish models

(available here: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html)

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.examples;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.tregex.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

import java.util.*;


public class TregexExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // set up pipeline
    Properties props = StringUtils.argsToProperties("-props", "StanfordCoreNLP-spanish.properties");
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    // Spanish example
    Annotation spanishDoc = new Annotation("...insert Spanish text...");
    pipeline.annotate(spanishDoc);
    // get first sentence
    CoreMap firstSentence = spanishDoc.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class).get(0);
    Tree firstSentenceTree = firstSentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
    // use Tregex to match
    String nounPhrasePattern = "/grup\\.nom/";
    TregexPattern nounPhraseTregexPattern = TregexPattern.compile(nounPhrasePattern);
    TregexMatcher nounPhraseTregexMatcher = nounPhraseTregexPattern.matcher(firstSentenceTree);
    while (nounPhraseTregexMatcher.find()) {
      nounPhraseTregexMatcher.getMatch().pennPrint();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Should I do the same with the verb group changing the  nounPhrasePattern?

Comment: Yes just change it to "/grup\\.verb/".

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.